# Parsing a simple imperative language in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to parse the following simple imperative language in Coq:

```
Set Warnings "-notation-overridden,-parsing".
From Coq Require Import Bool.Bool.
From Coq Require Import Init.Nat.
From Coq Require Import Arith.Arith.
From Coq Require Import Arith.EqNat.
From Coq Require Import omega.Omega.
From Coq Require Import Lists.List.
From Coq Require Import Strings.String.
Import ListNotations.

Definition vname := string.
Definition val := Z.

Inductive type :=
| Int: type.

Inductive expr :=
| var : vname -> expr
| int : val -> expr
| add : expr -> expr -> expr.

Inductive com :=
| Skip : com
| Seq : com -> com -> com
| Bind : vname -> type -> com -> com
| Assign : vname -> expr -> com.

Bind Scope move_scope with com.
Notation "'SKIP'" :=
  Skip : move_scope.
Notation "c1 ;; c2" :=
  (Seq c1 c2) (at level 80, right associativity) : move_scope.
Notation "'LET' x ':' t 'IN' b 'END'" :=
  (Bind x t b) (at level 80, right associativity) : move_scope.
Notation "x '::=' e" :=
  (Assign x e) (at level 60) : move_scope.

Definition prog0 : com := SKIP.

Definition prog1 : com := (LET "x" : Int IN SKIP END).
```

However, trying to parse a let expression gives an error:

> Syntax error: ':' expected after [constr:operconstr level 200] (in
>   [constr:operconstr]).

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `:` is a reserved Coq keyword. Unfortunately `::` (concatenates a list head and tail) is also reserved. You may use `:::` - or any other notation you like -

```
Notation "'LET' x ':::' t 'IN' b 'END'" :=
  (Bind x t b) (at level 40, right associativity) : move_scope.
Definition prog1 : com := (LET "x" ::: Int IN SKIP END).
```

Comment: Ok, so the forbidden tokens are written in https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#other-tokens and I guess the above message is just saying that it did not find : in the right place according to its definition. It would be interesting to see where : is defined.